# ClassCastException: Cannot cast FacesInitializer to ServletContainerInitializer with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

After i add `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` to my JSF project it stops working with the error:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers Failed to process JAR found at URL [/RegaloCE] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [{1}]

java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

Well, the server (apache tomcat 8) doesn't have this library in it and i am not using maven.
Tried some answers from here (stackoverflow) but nothing helped..

thx

**full stacktrace**

```
07-May-2014 14:53:51.111 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers Failed to process JAR found at URL [/RegaloCE] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [{1}]
 java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:768)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5058)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1554)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1448)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Does `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` contain `javax.servlet.*` classes? If so, it's not legal to put that into your web application. If you want Java EE in Tomcat, why not use TomEE and get it out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since i was using NetBeans 8 and i couldn't use TomEE with JEE Web 7, i had to put javax.ejb inside {tomcat-home}/lib..

Unfortunately netbeans still doesn't recognize it so i updated the `project.properties` inside `nbproject` folder and add `${j2ee.server.home}/lib/javax.ejb-api-3.2.jar` to the `j2ee.platform.classpath` property..

Now netbeans recognizes the lib and build with it and i don't need to include in the project libs..

(the only thing i needed inside java ee web api was the annotations and ejb, now i'm loading them manually..